# Using MassTransit in file process scenario

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am new to MassTransit and for at least a week digging through documentation and GitHub sample projects. So I still have a couple of question on the topic.

I have a business scenario of processing an `.xlsx` file with companies org. structures, in result producing a bunch of entities for users and their departments.

My main questions are:

1. Is it possible to implement the way where I can wait for users decision on this "**request**" ? E.g, if he wan't to cancel org. structure uploading, it should not save anything in DB at all.
   And in opposite, if user steps were tend to Completed task, user and department entities should be saved in DBContext.
2. If yes, how can I use it with EntityFramework Core? Where should I use await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(), in order to persist transaction like described in first question.

I need an answer of how to correctly piece up pretty MassTransit abstractions suited for my case.

Thanks in advance for any help, links, sources!

Comment: Batch Sample: https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Batch

Comment: I don't see there about waiting for users iteraction

Comment: Some things are left to the developer to figure out.

Comment: So the actual mechanism is the Request/Response approach? Where I am producing responses from activites or sagas in my hosted backgound serivce and then GetResponse from API for example?